# Why does conda want to downgrade everything to Python 2.7 when my package is Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, conda, conda-build

I'm trying to upgrade our application to Python 3, but cannot get conda to accept that the package is compatible.

The package appears to build OK and appears to be a Python 3 package:

```
 λ conda search jbagdal --info

jbagdal 2.2.0 py36_vc15hca0d6c3_0
---------------------------------
file name   : jbagdal-2.2.0-py36_vc15hca0d6c3_0.tar.bz2
name        : jbagdal
version     : 2.2.0
build       : py36_vc15hca0d6c3_0
build number: 0
size        : 8.7 MB
subdir      : win-64
url         : file://devserver/conda_packages/win-64/jbagdal-2.2.0-py36_vc15hca0d6c3_0.tar.bz2
md5         : 600a8...770e9
timestamp   : 2019-07-02 14:42:03 UTC
dependencies:
  - geos
  - numpy
  - proj4
  - python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0
  - sqlite
```

However, when I create a fresh conda environment using Python 3.6.8 and attempt to install the package, I get the message that many dependencies will be downgraded to Python 2.7.

```
λ conda install jbagdal

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  certifi                                  2019.6.16-py36_0 --> 2019.6.16-py27_0
  pip                                         19.1.1-py36_0 --> 19.1.1-py27_0
  python                                   3.6.8-h9f7ef89_7 --> 2.7.15-h2880e7c_4
  setuptools                                  41.0.1-py36_0 --> 41.0.1-py27_0
  vc                                        14.1-h0510ff6_4 --> 9-h7299396_1
  wheel                                       0.33.4-py36_0 --> 0.33.4-py27_0
  wincertstore                           0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0 --> 0.2-py27hf04cefb_0
```

I've looked this up and some people have suggested explicitly specifying the Python version, but that does not work either.

```
 λ conda install jbagdal python==3.6.8
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - jbagdal
  - python==3.6.8
Use "conda search <package> --info" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What is wrong with my package? Why does conda not believe it is a Python 3 package? What do I need to change in the recipe to get it to build as Python 3.

**meta.yaml**

```
package:
  name: jbagdal
  version: 2.2.0

source:
  git_rev: trunk
  git_url: https://srcserver/GDAL/gdal.git

build:
  features:
    - vc9     [win and py27]
    - vc10    [win and py34]
    - vc14    [win and py35]
    - vc15    [win and py>=36]

requirements:
  build:
    - swig
    - sqlite
    - python
    - numpy
    - setuptools
    - {{ compiler('c') }}
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}

  run:
    - python
    - sqlite
    - numpy
    - geos
    - proj4

about:
  home: www.gdal.org
  license:
  license_file:
```

**Output of conda info**

```
     active environment : deleteme
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\deleteme
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\jontwo\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\jontwo\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.8
    conda-build version : 3.0.15
         python version : 2.7.15.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2  (writable)
           channel URLs : file://devserver/conda_packages/win-64
                          file://devserver/conda_packages/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs
                          C:\Users\jontwo\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\jontwo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs
                          C:\Users\jontwo\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\jontwo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.8 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.15 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Conda build command does specify Python version:

```
conda build . --output-folder v:\conda_packages --python=3.6.8
```

And the current conda environment is Python 3.6.8:

```
 λ python --version
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Comment: I think you need the `--use-local` flag to install packages you've built yourself

Comment: On which command, `conda install`? It is picking up the local package, just doesn't recognise it as Python 3.

Comment: Clearly, its not picking up the right package, otherwise it wouldn't try to downgrade. Its odd that its not even trying to download the appropriate package, hence why I think you need `--use-local` if you've built the package yourself on the `conda install ... python==3.6.8` command.

Comment: `--use-local` just gives me this error: `UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda2/conda-bld`

Comment: If I remove the Python 2.7 package from the channel though, I now get `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - jbagdal -> *[track_features=vc15]`

Comment: Then that channel is not available to you? I'm not sure, but the track_features is not something I've seen on a package in a while. Maybe that's it?

Comment: Any idea what it is? It's quite hard to Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is that `meta.yaml` is incorrect.

```
    - vc14    [win and py35]
    - vc15    [win and py>=36]
```

should be

```
    - vc14    [win and py>=35]
```

The `[track_features]` error was because `conda` was looking for `vc15` on the local machine before it would install. Once I changed it back to `vc14`, everything worked fine.